# Chainlink performUpkeep not being executed

Tags: chainlink-vrf, chainlink-automation

I am trying to implement a decentralized raffle that works with custom tokens and randomly select the winner using chainlink automated keepers. I selected a time-based keeper so that "performUpkeep" will be called every 15 minutes.
However,I've run into a problem that I just can't figure out.
So I have this contract: [initial TokenRaffle contract](https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0x71563abEb9efCac0CB186aD687c84D7F2D1d6190#code). I am listening for the RequestedRaffleWinner() event in the front end code, so everytime it is emitted there will be a console.log. And it works. Every 15 minutes the RequestedRaffleWinner() event is being emitted , just as intended. However, there were some things I wanted to change in the smart contract, so I tried deploying another similar one but the RequestedRaffleWinner event was no longer being called. I racked my brains trying to figure it out and in the end I wanted to check something. I took the initial contract code, and deployed it again at a different address [copy of initial TokeRaffle](https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0x6C2778C32f82EAAcF7b599D346ECA3182BA2DDe4#readContract). I did everything exactly the same way, but for this contract, still there is nothing logged to the console and I get this message on etherscan: "Although one or more Error Occurred [execution reverted] Contract Execution Completed". I don't understand how this could happen only for the second contract even if they are identical. The problem with the first contract is that I cannot enter the raffle because the raffle state is not being updated properly. The problem with the second contract is I cannot pick a winner of the raffle. Can someone please explain how I could get an option where both entering the raffle and picking a winner work?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148217/discussion-on-question-by-yksooh-chainlink-performupkeep-not-being-executed); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.